# Google BigQuery returns same value for visiId and visitStartTime

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I run this very simple query on BigQuery and it returned the visitId value as visit start time. Code is below and you can also see the screenshot here: [visitStartTime and visitId same value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE4eh.png)

```
SELECT visitStartTime, visitId FROM [83606741.ga_sessions_intraday_20160606] group by visitStartTime, visitId order by visitStartTime DESC;
```

How can I get the session start time to be shown like 11:45 and what is the reason these two columns have the same value?

Thank you for the replies!

Comment: the visitId is usually the same as the visitStartTime, but these can get different values, e.g. when a user starts two different sessions in the same second. For the start of a visit always use visitStartTime to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function will return the time of the visit.

```
SELECT time(SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(visitid)) as visit_time FROM [83606741.ga_sessions_intraday_20160606]
```

Like you say, visitID is the same as visitstarttime.  For this reason visitid is not a unique reference for a session.  To create a unique sessionid you need to concatenate it with the visitorid:

```
concat(fullvisitorid, string(visitid)) as sessionid
```

Comment: Maybe an interesting edition to this answer is delivered in this blog (difference between visitStarTime and visitId). https://www.conversionworks.co.uk/blog/2018/07/25/bigquery-caveat-two-exits-from-one-google-analytics-session/

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically need hours and minutes, one way to do it is using FORMAT_UTC_USEC, HOUR, and MINUTE functions as follows.

```
SELECT 
FORMAT_UTC_USEC(visitStartTime * 1000000) AS time, 
HOUR(FORMAT_UTC_USEC(visitStartTime * 1000000)) AS hour, 
MINUTE(FORMAT_UTC_USEC(visitStartTime * 1000000)) AS minute
FROM ...
```

Visit https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#datetimefunctions for more details.